# Embed Yammer Feed into a Wordpress Page

Tags: wordpress, yammer

Our enterprise is currently on Yammer and also has a intranet built using Wordpress. I'd like to embed the Yammer feed to a couple of groups that I admin on specific pages of our intranet relevant to those groups.

Problem is, when I add the Yammer embed code (from copying the 'embed this feed' link in the group) to the Wordpress Page using the 'text' editor (not visual) I get no result.

This a copy of the code I am using (with dummy 'network' and 'group':

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:800px;width:400px;"></div>
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script> yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed",
    network: "domain.com",
    feedType: "group",
    feedId: "123456"});
</script>
```

All I get back on the intranet published page is this text right at the bottom after a big gap of white space.

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
container: “#embedded-feed”,
network: “domain.com”,
feedType: “group”,
feedId: “123456″});

Edit this entry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to paste the code into WordPress and WordPress is not accepting it. You cannot embed JavaScript as easily as pasting it in. You'll need to read the WordPress documentation to find the best way to put JS into your WP site:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-javascript-to-a-single-page

https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-add-javascript-in-a-wordpress-post-or-page-1845